# MySQL Workbench 6.3 How do I run queries that contain [ ]

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I was given a .sql file to setup a database, and it appears that I am unable to run it because it contains [] and MySQL Workbench says that it's a syntax error.

So I was wondering if there was a way to run it without using SQL Server Management studio as I'm not able to connect to the SQL Server using it apparently...

Comment: Backticks (`\``) are the MySQL version of SQL Server's `[]` escaping.  But the second part of your question confuses me.  Is your DBMS SQL Server or MySQL?  Are you trying to query a SQL Server database using MySQL Workbench...?

Comment: MySQL Workbench works only with MySQL servers. You cannot use it for MS SQL Server or any other.

Answer (score 0):

The qualifiers are part of database SQL dialect. You can't execute SQL Server code on MySQL without the necessary modifications (if possible at all)